# Why is $L^p$ a generalization of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the $p$-norm.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why is $L^p$ a natural generalization of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the $p$-norm? If I have $f\in L^p$, this represents a mapping from a measurable set to the real numbers. How can I view a finite-dimensional vector as a function in $L^p$ so that I can see this is a generalization?

Comment: $L^p$ is a space. An space can't be a generalization of a norm. The $p$-norm defined on $L^p$ is a generalization of the $p$-norm defined on $R^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $F$ be a finite but non-empty set. Consider on $F$ the counting measure $\mu$ (that is, if $A\subset F$, then $\mu(A)=\#A$). Then every function from $F$ into $[0,\infty]$ is measurable. And, if $F=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, and $f$ is a function from $F$ into $\Bbb R$, then $f\in L^p(F)$ and$$\|f\|_p=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\bigl|f(x_k)\bigr|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

Comment: Does this mean that every element of the domain is like a dimension? Then is a continuous function like a vector with uncountable dimmension?

Comment: I don't understand what you are writing. Every element of $F$ is simply a point and what I did proves that, if $f$ is a function from $F$ into $\Bbb R$, then $\|f\|_p$ is $\bigl\|(f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)\bigr\|_p$.  Since there is no topology on $F$, you cannot speak of continuity here. Finally, I don't know what is a vector with uncountable dimension. Actually, I don't know what is the meaning of dimension of a vector.

Comment: The dimension of a vector is the number of its entries.

Comment: A vector doesn't have to have entries. Consider de vector space of all continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$. What are the entries of the exponential function, for instance?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, so the p-norm we define on a finite dimensional vector space, but this could be generalized to a certain class of infinite dimensional vector spaces by the $L^p$ norm?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I apologize for my imprecise language, I am taking an intro functional analysis course and I am trying to pinpoint my confusion.

Comment: Yes, the $L^p$ spaces are infinite-dimensional generalizations of $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n)$ endowed with the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of measure theory, consider the set $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with its power set $\mathscr{F}:=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Any vector $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\intercal\in\mathbb{C}^n$ can be considered as a function $\mathbf{x}:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by $\mathbf{x}(n)=x_n$. In this setting, it is clear that $\mathbf{x}$ is $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$-measurable. Consider the counting measure $\kappa$ on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$

Notice that
$$\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}|x_n|^p\Big)^{1/p}=\Big(\int_\Omega|\mathbf{x}(n)|^p\,\kappa(dn)\Big)^{1/p}$$

This shows how can consider the $L_p$-norm as a *generalization* of the $p$-norm in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Same comment I left on the other answer, does this mean that every element of the domain is like a dimension? Then is a continuous function essentailly a vector with uncountable dimmension?

Comment: I don't want to go too much into the weeds of set theory, but  a function $f$ from a set $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$ is an element of the [product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_products_of_several_sets) $\mathbb{R}^\Omega$. The component of  $f$ in the $x$-th coordinate is $f(x)$. For measure theory purposes one works only with a subclass of functions (measurable functions relative to some $\sigma$-algebra). When $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra of the power set, $\mathbb{R}^\Omega$ and the power series measurable functions coincide.